# how we install Android SDK in Ubuntu for development?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools

I am new on Ubuntu.I want to install Android Sdk on this, because i am an android Developer. i have downloded Android Sdk For Linux from the folowing site.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

but i have idea how i can install this. i have read many tutorials but not perfect. 
http://androidonubuntu.blogspot.com/
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Android-on-Ubuntu-Linux-with-Eclipse-IDE

anybody can help? Thanks.

Comment: just start eclipse that comes with the bundle and its enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a folder with any name (mostly we prefer name as workspace) where ever you want
- Unzip the downloaded file. You will have 2 folders. 1) Eclipse and 2) sdk
- goto eclipse folder and run eclipse.exe file
- Eclipse window will open >> browse and give path of your latest created folder(This is your workspace now onwards)

You can create projects in eclipse now..

You are done. Nothing much is required.